# Check if SAP exists from the UI

Tags: marketing-cloud, sender-authentication-package

I have inherited an account and now I've been asked to check whether SAP exists for this account or not.

The only thing that comes to my mind is to check if URLs are customized in Web Studio, which they are not - but I think it's possible to have SAP without the custom domain.

Is there any other way to check, without opening a support ticket, to find out if we have SAP in this account and what it's set to?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is to go to Email Studio > Email > Admin > Account Settings > There will be a section called "Authenticated Domains".

It will show your SAP domain if exists. If not it will be blank.

Below is the screenshot:

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can go through several places.
I would say the Web Studio approach is sufficient; as far as I know the SAP actually does not come without it.

But you can get more indications:

- Upload an image in Content Builder, what is its URL?
- Check Email Studio / Admin / From Address management, do you see anything listed as "verified"?
- Send out an actual email to yourself, check the mail headers, does it say something about DKIM or SPF? Also check the the bounce / reply headers etc.  Alternatively, send out an email to a tool like mail-tester.com which does interpret this for you. If you do not have DKIM / SPF set up, then you have no SAP.